# How to query 2 tables

Tags: php, join

I need to sum the transactions in `tblgl (tblgl.SUM(InMonthActual))` for a selection of cost centres (tblgl.CostCentreCode) where the following conditions are met:

1. `tblgl.PeriodNumber = 2`
2. `tblgl.CostCentreCode = tblcostcentrehierarchy.CostCentreCode
   WHERE tblcostcentrehierarchy.Level7 = "RWK312 CORPORATE"`
3. `tblgl.CostCentreCode = tblcostcentreallocations.CostCentreCode
   WHERE tblcostcentreallocations.Username = "jonest"`

At the moment I'm running 3 separate queries to create an array which is used in the next query.

Is there a way to do it in one (maybe using **JOIN**)?

Comment: You should probably use a couple of subqueries.  But could you post the actual 3 queries, and we can combine from there?

Comment: Post the queries which you are already using. That will help us to solve your problem more precisely.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this query will fetch your desire data. Check and let me know if it works for you.

```
   SELECT SUM(tb1.`InMonthActual`) 
   FROM `tblgl` as tb1 
   JOIN `tblcostcentrehierarchy` as tb2 ON tb1.`CostCetntreCode` = tb2.`CostCentreCode`
   JOIN `tblcostcentreallocations` as tb3 ON tb1.`CostCetntreCode` = tb3.`CostCentreCode`
   WHERE tb1.`PeriodNumber` = '2' AND tb2.`Level17` = "RWK312 CORPORATE" AND tb3.`Username` = "jonest"
```

Comment: Thanks Zohaib. It works as expected although it's not any quicker than running the queries separately.

Comment: My pleasure, It should quicker than multiple separate queries.

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
SELECT SUM(tblgl.InMonthActual) FROM tblgl
INNER JOIN tblcostcentrehierarchy ON (tblgl.CostCentreCode = tblcostcentrehierarchy.CostCentreCode AND tblgl.PeriodNumber = 2)
INNER JOIN tblcostcentreallocations ON  (tblgl.CostCentreCode = tblcostcentreallocations.CostCentreCode)
WHERE tblcostcentreallocations.Username = "jonest" AND tblcostcentrehierarchy.Level7 = "RWK312 CORPORATE"
GROUP BY tblgl.InMonthActual
```

Hope it works fine